# Error trying to query SQLite3 database in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I am trying to access an SQLite 3 database programmatically using the code below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        string connectionPath = @"Data Source=C:\temp\sms.db";

        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionPath);

        SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        connection.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Message";
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdaptor = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        dataAdaptor.Fill(dataset, "messages");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables["messages"];
        connection.Close();

    }

    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

However whenever I press the button this code is assigned to, it doesn't catch on the `Try` `Catch` and display my message box, it freezes for a few seconds and debugs into the Program.cs file at the line shown below

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmMainWindow()); **<----This Line**
    }
}
```

At that line it then displays this error to me

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.76.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies.
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

How can I overcome this error so I can query the database?

### EDIT

My development OS is Win 7 x64 Prof
I have installed:
Setups for 64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)
Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)
from here[system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Comment: Sounds like a 32-/64-bit mismatch. Is your development OS 64-bit?? If so: did you install both versions of SQLite? The tricky part is: since Visual Studio is 32-bit, you need the 32-bit version when running inside VS. If you run outside VS, you get the 64-bit version by default (unless you explicitly compile for "x86" only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out Visual Studio was incorrectly referencing a different version of System.Data.SQLite.dll for some reason

I removed the old reference, and copied the new System.Data.SQLite.dll files to the location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client

Then added reference to it using Visual Studio again and it now works

Answer (score 2):

What dll are you using? if you are in x64 system you have to use x64 dll of SQLite